# managing Google Bigable via Google development console

Tags: hbase

Getting hbase shell working on windows is a nightmare. Is it possible to use  Google development console for creating and managing BigTable.
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

We're working on doing just that.  We need to add some permissions to the development VM at startup in order to make that happen.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

In the meantime, I would suggest creating a small hadoop cluster with Cloud Bigtable options using bdutil or dataproc.  I haven't tried either through the development console, but I hope they work for you.

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/creating-hadoop-cluster
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/wordcount-mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using the hbase shell directly rather than the quickstart.  See https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/installing-hbase-shell on how to do that.